# R - ggplot geom_bar - Formatting y axis from scientific to comma, breaks issue - x axis categorical, y axis continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to create a simple bar chart in `ggplot2` with a categorical X (states)  and continuous Y (dollars spent) but the Y axis is displayed in scientific notation.

I'm not understanding why `scale_y_continuous(labels="comma")` is not working to do this.

An example of the data and error message are displayed below.

```
SS <- ggplot(statesummary,aes(factor(STATE),SPEND))+
        geom_bar(stat="identity",col="red",fill="white")+
        scale_y_continuous(labels="comma")

  "Error in scale_labels.continuous(scale, major) : 
   Breaks and labels are different lengths"  

  STATE     SPEND 
  NH        14,768,408 
  ME        882,312,066 
  RI        316,476,695 
  MA        2,939,600,063 
  CT        8,627,669,723 
  VT        968,411,831
```

Can someone please help me understand why this is and also what I should be doing?  It seems like it should be a very easy conversion that would not require breaks.

Comment: Please add your code and data.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: SS <- ggplot(statesummary,aes(factor(STATE),SPEND))+    
        geom_bar(stat="identity",col="red",fill="white")+    
        scale_y_continuous(labels="comma")

Comment: Error in scale_labels.continuous(scale, major) :     
  Breaks and labels are different lengths

Comment: STATE SPEND
NH  14,768,408 
ME  882,312,066 
RI  316,476,695 
MA  2,939,600,063 
CT  8,627,669,723 
VT  968,411,831

Comment: Please edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

There might be other issues, but the immediate one is that you need to remove the quotes around 'comma'.  Additionally make sure you have the scales package.